# can i get get the Reflection data by passing the class path rather than the class name?

Tags: php, reflection

i am making my own class autoloader and and am building an array from the results.

one of my array i would like it to look like

`$classes['myTestClass'] = ./classes/myTestClass.class.php`

I can build this array but what i cannot do is set the actual class name of the class being loaded as the key to the path.

this is my `foreach` loop that builds my array

```
foreach ($classIterator as $file) {

    if ($this->_searchFilter($file))
        $this->classes[] = $file->getPathname();
}
```

`$file->getPathname()` has the absolute path of the class file that will be `required`, how can i get the class name from that file?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are using naming convention so `/classes/myTestClass.class.php` declares `myTestClass`, then simple `str_replace` should be sufficient:

```
foreach ($classIterator as $file) {

    if ($this->_searchFilter($file))
        $classPath = $file->getPathname();
        $className = str_replace('.class.php', '', basename($classPath));
        $this->classes[$className] = $classPath;
}
```